# Gallery loading slowly

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thumbnails in php generated gallery loading slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384048/thumbnails-in-php-generated-gallery-loading-slow)

Code link can be found on the bottom of the page.

The site is running from 1and1.co.uk linux based system, good enough to load the gallery much faster than it currently does.

The php generated thumbnails are loading a bit slow, can you tell me why?

http://site-perf.com/cgi-bin/show.cgi?id=vz5le19Fp5E

code:
http://satinaweb.com/tmp/functions.txt

Here is `crop.php`:

```
$sourceimage = $_GET['a'];

function crop($sourceimage) {
    // Draw & resize
    header('Content-Type: $imsz[\'mime\']');

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($sourceimage);

    if($width > $height){
        $new_width = 100;
        $new_height = 75;
    } else {
        $new_width = 75;
        $new_height = 100;
    }

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceimage);
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($image_p);
    imagedestroy($image_p);
    imagedestroy($image);
} 

crop($sourceimage);
```

If you have questions, please ask!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, hopefully you'll get an answer for your problem. However you shouldn't post duplicate questions. It would be better to edit the original question and flag it for re-opening. You should read the [FAQ] too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should have noticed from your site-perf graph most is that,

I'm not going to look through all your code, but you have a file called `crop.php`. This is going to be slow because it (presumably) crops the images on every page load, which takes a relatively long time (made apparent from the site-perf data); for each request, the browser spends most of it's time waiting for the server to respond.

You should consider using a cache folder to store cropped images and serve them up as-is to reduce loading time.

In `crop.php`, you could do something like this (pseudo code):

```
IF original image newer than cropped OR cropped doesn't exist
    Load original image
    Crop original image
    Save cropped image to cache folder
ELSE
    Serve already-cropped image from cache
ENDIF
```

---

Every time you call `crop()`, you read the image, modify it and spit it out to the client. This is incredibly wasteful, because you need to re-process the image for every request. You're even destroying the image afterwards (not that this makes much difference). Instead, use [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) with a cache directory, and save the image to disk as well as sending it to the client.

Now, your script might look like this:

```
$sourceimage = $_GET['a'];

$cache_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/cache";        // Cache directory
$cache_file = $cache_dir . '/' . $source_image; // Path to cached image

function crop($sourceimage) {
    header('Content-Type: $imsz[\'mime\']');

    // If cached version of cropped image doesn't exist, create it
    if(!is_file($cache_file)) {     
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($sourceimage);

        if($width > $height) {
            $new_width = 100;
            $new_height = 75;
        } else {
            $new_width = 75;
            $new_height = 100;
        }

        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceimage);
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        imagejpeg($image_p, $cache_file);   // Save image file to disk
    } else {    // If cached file exists, output to browser without processing
        echo file_get_contents($cache_file);
    }
} 

crop($sourceimage);
```

**This is untested, but should work.** Please don't just copy and paste the above code; read through it and make sure you understand how and why it does what it does.

Comment: crop.php: http://satinaweb.com/tmp/crop.txt

Comment: hi i modified the cache after your suggestion, i defined the cachedir:
$cachedir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/imagecache";
$cache_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . $cachedir;
but after i run the cache.php, than i check in the /imagecache dir, it is empty.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting turned on and see if your script outputs any errors. What I have written may not work, as I have said in my answer.

Comment: no it had a tiny error in the following line
$cache_file = $cache_dir . '/' . $source_image; // correct: $sourceimage i removed the underscore. i didnt found anymore error. i check the error reporting now.

Comment: am i right that the $cache_dir directory sould be filled with the small thumbnail jpg files?

Comment: but its empty. :(
i dont want to bother you can't we chat somewhere? it would be a bit faster.
im clueless...

Comment: now it looks better, i only have to create within the function the directories (if theyre not existing) and some way after first run i have to reload the gallery to get the thumbs. thies 2 things have to be solved and we arrived :) thanks for helping me!

Comment: That's quite alright. SO is always here to help. I'm glad you've solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your page is loading slowly due to HTTP requests being queued.

Although each image is small, the requests are spending a large proportion of their time queued, waiting for other requests to finish before they start, in the worst cases, they are waiting for one and a half seconds before they even start downloading.

The second delay is then caused by the time it takes to create the images.

The actual download was nearly instant after waiting for these other processes.

1. Queued 1600ms
2. Waiting 986ms
3. Download 0ms

Rather than generate the correct sized images every time, why not store the result to be used on subsequent visits - this means the page will be slow once and then much faster all other times.

If the time your script took to crop the images was shorted, the queueing would be shorter too. Here is an example...

1. Check in a folder for the cropped image
2. If it exists, serve it (no computation required)
3. If it doesn't exist, generate it
4. Save the result in the folder to cache it

Comment: thanks! i have now near 3000 images. i plan to have more 10thousands, or maybe once 100.000 images. will the hosting company be happy if i store the thumbs & the original images either?

Comment: @SatinaNichols it depends on the hosting company - but personally I find disk-space to be cheaper than processing power so I would rather have all images cached once they have been generated.

Comment: youre right! thanks. i'll think and read after, and ill create the php file from the pseudo you wrote.